# Refactor a query with two subselects in WHERE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following scope on the Project model to find projects to which at least 80 crowdfunding pledges have been done or projects which have reached their goal already:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :popular, -> { collecting.where("80 <= (?) OR goal <= (?)",
    Pledge.select('COUNT(*)').where("project_id = projects.id").where(paid: true),
    Pledge.select('SUM(amount)').where("project_id = projects.id").where(paid: true))
  }

  (...)
end
```

This works just fine and produces the following SQL for Postres:

```
Project.popular
# SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."state" = 'collecting' AND (80 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pledges"  WHERE (project_id = projects.id) AND "pledges"."paid" = 't') OR goal <= (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM "pledges"  WHERE (project_id = projects.id) AND "pledges"."paid" = 't'))
```

It's important to get the count as well:

```
Project.popular.count
# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."state" = 'collecting' AND (80 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pledges" WHERE (project_id = projects.id) AND "pledges"."paid" = 't') OR goal <= (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM "pledges" WHERE (project_id = projects.id) AND "pledges"."paid" = 't'))
```

Okay, the subselects are nice, but I have this feeling that there's a better and more efficient way to do this. I've tried `joins` and `sum`, but the mandatory `group` to use aggregate functions breaks `Project.popular.count`.

Any ideas how to refactor this? Maybe just a way to do `where("project_id = projects.id")` in Hash notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is any good for you because I can't express the below query in the ActiveRecord lingo but if you can it will be a big improvement over the poor query currently being generated

```
select "projects".*, project_count, project_amount
from
    "projects"
    inner join (
        select
            id,
            count(*) as project_count,
            sum(amount) as project_amount
        from pledges
        group by id
        where paid
    ) pledges using (id)
where
    "projects"."state" = 'collecting'
    and
    (project_count >= 80 or project_amount >= goal)
```

Comment: A few touches were necessary to get this to work, see my answer below for the working version.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Clodonaldo! With a few litte touches, your query works like a charm:

```
select "projects".*, pledges_count, pledges_sum
from
    "projects"
    inner join (
        select
            project_id as id,
            count(*) as pledges_count,
            sum(amount) as pledges_sum
        from pledges
        where paid
        group by project_id
    ) pledges using (id)
where
    "projects"."state" = 'collecting'
    and
    (pledges_count >= 80 or pledges_sum >= goal)
```

Not sure thou whether AR or AREL can build this.

UPDATE:

The shortest I can come up with is (I don't need the count and sum values):

```
Project.collecting.joins(
    "INNER JOIN (",
    Pledge.paid.group(:project_id).select("
      project_id AS id,
      COUNT(*) AS count,
      SUM(amount) AS sum
    ").to_sql,
    ") pledges USING (id)"
  ).where("count >= 80 OR sum >= goal")
```

The above produces:

```
SELECT "projects".*
FROM
    "projects"
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT
            project_id AS id,
            COUNT(*) AS count,
            SUM(amount) AS sum
        FROM "pledges"
        WHERE "pledges"."paid" = 't'
        GROUP BY project_id
    ) pledges USING (id)
WHERE
    "projects"."state" = 'collecting'
    AND
    (count >= 80 OR sum >= goal)
```